# Pushing numbers into an array using a for loop. (Find GCF of given number)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find the GCF of any number I pass into my function.
When I alert my storage array, all I get is 0.

Why is the only value in my storage array 0? Even though the loop ran 12 times, why are my values not being pushed into the storage array?

```js
let gcf = num => {
  let storage = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    // if it divides evenly into num, it is a factor and we want to push it
    // into an array
    if (i % num == 0) {
      storage.push(i);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  // will sort the array from highest to lowest 
  storage = storage.sort((a, b) => {
    return b - a;
  })
  alert(storage[0]);
  // and return storage[0] for the gcf
}

gcf(12);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modulo operator was backwards ;)

```js
let gcf = num => {
  let storage = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
    // if it divides evenly into num, it is a factor and we want to push it
    // into an array
    if (num % i == 0) {
      storage.push(i);
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  // will sort the array from highest to lowest 
  storage = storage.sort((a, b) => {
    return a - b;
  })
  alert(storage[0]);
  // and return storage[0] for the gcf
}

gcf(12);
```